# It is an anagrams program which ignores case sensitive

Tags: java, arrays

**anagrams program**

```
        int len1 = a.length();
        int len2 = b.length();
        char[] arr1 = a.toCharArray();
        char[] arr2 = b.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr1);
        Arrays.sort(arr2);

        if (String.valueOf(arr1).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(arr2))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**RESULT**
input
String1 = Hello
String2 = hello
but my result is showing not anagram 
I want to print it has to anagram

*my screenshot:*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR9Cy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are sorting on the `char[]` without ignoring the casing, `Hello` does not sort the same as `hello`.

`Hello` would be sorted to `Hello`.

`hello` would be sorted to `ehllo`.

To fix this you can set your `String` values to lowercase before you convert then into arrays by doing this:

```
a = a.toLowerCase();
b = b.toLowerCase();
char[] arr1 = a.toCharArray();
char[] arr2 = b.toCharArray();
```

Comment: okay. I have another doubt how to sort alphabets manually without using Arrays.sort method

Answer (score 0):

It might help to know that upper and lower case ASCII characters are always 32 apart, as a bit of helpful knowledge, though I agree with Nexevis's approach of setting the strings to lowercase before comparing them.